# how to deal in a pythonic way with list of arrays or single array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this issue:

in my software I am either dealing with a single array or a list of 3 arrays (they are 1 or 3 components of a pixelized sky map).

If the single array was a list of 1 array, then it would be very easy to iterate over it transparently, regardless the number of elements.

Now, let's say I want to square these maps:

```
my_map = np.ones(100) # case of single component
# my_map = [np.ones(100) for c in [0, 1, 2]] # case of 3 components

if isinstance(my_map, list): #this is ugly
    my_map_2 = [m**2 for m in my_map]
else:
    my_map = my_map ** 2
```

would you have any suggestion on how to improve this?

Comment: You can convert your single element to a list.. That way you don't have to have that extra `isinstance` check..

Comment: I can, the problem is that then I should extract the 0th element of the list to go back to a single array, so it is not very elegant either...

Comment: @Andrea.. That you would have to do anyway to extract values from other list.. Anyway you are having list of arrays only right?? 1, 2 or 3

Comment: @Rohit Jain: or the opposite: convert 3 components to a single numpy array ([`numpy.concatenate()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)). Then `a**2` works in both cases

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian.. Yeah that would also do better..

Comment: having a list of 1 array is not acceptable, if it is only 1 component, then it should just be an array of that component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you directly create a 2D array ?

```
my_array = np.ones((100,3), dtype=float)
```

That way, you could directly square your 'three' arrays at once. You could still access individual elements as:

```
(x, y, z) = my_array.T
```

where `.T` is a shortcut for the `.transpose` method.

Using this approach would be far more efficient than looping on a list, especially if you apply the same function to the three arrays. Even if you want, say, to square the first array, double the second and take the square root of the third, you could:

```
my_array[:,0] **=2
my_array[:,1] *=2
my_array[:,2] **=0.5
```

Comment: no, for compatibility I need also to support the case of a list of 3 arrays, or a tuple of 3 arrays.

Comment: You could go back very easily to a list of three arrays with `my_array=my_array.T.tolist()`. It's far more efficient to apply the same function at once on a larger array than three times on smaller ones...

Comment: so let's say my function accepts a single array or a list of 3 arrays or a tuple of 3 arrays, then at the beginning of the function should I call `np.asarray`?

Comment: That depends on the signature of your function: do you have a particular example in mind? Your `np.asarray` will transform your list (or tuple) of three arrays as a `(3,N)` array, copying the data (the daat won't be copied if you pass a `ndarray` as input).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your return value to list if it is a single value.. using list() factory method..

```
my_map = []
temp = np.ones(100) # case of single component
# Append your temp value.. either single or a list to your empty list..
my_map.append(temp)
my_map_2 = [m**2 for m in my_map]
```

I assume that your method `np.ones(100)` may return a single value and even a list..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `numpy.asarray`?  Then the if-else would just be

```
my_map = numpy.asarray(my_map)**2
```

Also check out `numpy.asanyarray` if you want to handle subclasses of ndarrays as well.

I often put a `numpy.asarray` call at the beginning of my functions, so they work on both lists and arrays.